# jQuery UI Tooltip: Manipulate DOM position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

By default, jQuery UI Tooltips' DOM elements are appended to the body right before `</body>`. Is there a way to have them right after the element which contains the title attribute the tooltip is referring to instead, so that the tooltip can be selected without any additional class (using `tooltipClass`)?

Comment: Some widgets have an `appendTo` option but this one doesn't seem to have one. Maybe raise a feature request?

Comment: By the way I didn't get what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there is a different way.

Comment: What exactly didn't you get? If I add an additional class to jQuery UI Tooltips' DOM element, which is appended to the body right before `</body>` I can select that class and apply CSS to it. Instead of that, I'd like to append the tooltip element in the right context, e.g. right after an `a` element containing the corresponding `title` attribute. Thus I could select the tooltip via `$('a.someclass').next('.ui-tooltip')` without the need of any additional tooltip class.

Comment: If your issue is just styling then modifying the DOM position seems unnecessary for me... Applying a class using widget while tooltip is created and using it to style will be performance wise better than querying the DOM for tooltips later, then applying the class...

Comment: If there is an option to control the DOM position of jQuery UI's tooltips, it doesn't really matter if I select the tooltip via `$('.someClassAddedThroughTooltipClass')` or via `$('a.someClass').next('.ui-tooltip')`, does it?

Comment: If the plugin adds a class of your choice, then can't you simply declare the styles for that CSS class in style sheet? BTW the first selector above will be faster than the second anyway.

Comment: Yes, I can. Well, not perceptibly I guess. My motivation is to keep the JS code short and clean so I would prefer to not add additional classes through JS.

Comment: *"My motivation is to keep the JS code short and clean so I would prefer to not add additional classes through JS"* - Isn't the best way to do that just to use the built in option of widget and define styles in CSS? I don't see any point in the use case or this discussion. If you really want that option for some reason raise a feature request with jQuery UI. Good luck.

Comment: With *"built in option of widget"* you mean `tooltipClass`? *"If you really want that option for some reason raise a feature request with jQuery UI."* So the answer to my original question is No?

Comment: Of course not, after all it's JavaScript and I'm pretty sure it's possible. But modifying the plugin might take much more time than someone already familiar with it's source. And there should be a good use case for spending such time looking under the hood of plugin? (and even if someone customizes the plugin, unless it's a feature request + pull request that gets merged into jQuery UI you'll have to maintain your custom copy which is not that great)

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's not possible with the existing options and without modifying the plugin. Thank you!