# jQueryUI Tooltip + Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet, html5-fullscreen

my question is somewhat related to this question: [jQuery UI Tooltip: Manipulate DOM position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080756/jquery-ui-tooltip-manipulate-dom-position)

In my case I'm using Leaflet and the HTML5 Fullscreen API to make it possible to display the map in fullscreen. I also use jQueryUI tooltip to be able to display some information when hovering over certain elements on the map. Unfortunately the tooltips are covered by the map when in fullscreen mode. So they are present but "under" the map.

As far as I understood from [the fullscreen spec](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#new-stacking-layer) a new layer is added when using fullscreen, which is above every other layer. So naturally the tooltip wouldn't be visible since jQueryUI appends the tooltip at the end of the body and the fullscreen is applied to the map which is in a div in the body.

I need these tooltips to be visible in fullscreen mode. So I suppose I'll need to append the tooltip to the div of the map instead. So the fullscreen mode also consideres the tooltip to be in the top layer.

Back to the first link: It says it's not possible to change the DOM position of the tooltip.

Can someone help as to how I can proceed on this issue? Or is it just not possible? Any tips appreciated.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lturfv2/

(from the Javascript)

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    fullscreenControl: true,
    fullscreenControlOptions: {
    position: 'topleft'
  }
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a 
  href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

$(document).tooltip();
```

The control elements have their tooltips which are displayed when hovered in the "small" version of the map. If switched to fullscreen (the blank control button) the tooltips aren't displayed anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sounds like something that can be fixed via CSS, adjusting the `z-index` maybe, but I am not sure. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Looking at the other question, OP was not interested in creating more code, but using the standard Tooltips execution, this does not allow the moving of the `<div>` elements or an `appendTo` option. Using `$.widget()` (the widget factory) you could roll your own way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example, it's not clear what may be happening.

At least with jQuery UI Modal, it does work as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x7wc51qk/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#show-diag-btn").click(function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog("open");
  })
});
```

Example is built from https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ and https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

**Update**

Your fiddle was configured incorrectly. I forked it and updated the resources properly:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hv7ak1rb/

Tooltips work as expected after the update. I found jQuery UI 1.9.0 CSS in use with jQuery UI 1.12.4. Updated this to the proper CSS.

Make sure your HTML is loading the resources properly and in the right order.

That should help.

Comment: This code doesn't use any fullscreen functionality so it doesn't have anything to do with the problem. I'm trying to recreate the situation in jsfiddle since I can't share the project code, but might take a while.

Comment: added the example to the question!

Comment: @xen I did not go into Full Screen mode. It is more clear what the issue may be at this point. Will investigate more.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) let me know if you have ANY new information on this issue, maybe I can find something myself with more information.